# Ruby "File.open" doesn't work if launched through Window's command prompt or Linux's Terminal (no error)

Tags: ruby, windows, terminal, command-prompt, raspbian

I have this Ruby program that I created under Windows 7. At several points through it I need to create a couple of files, so I use the following bit of code:

```
File.open('my_file.txt', "w") {|file| file.puts 'the stuff I want to put inside' }
```

It works pretty well if I launch the program by double clicking on it, but it doesn't work if I launch it through the command prompt.
I get no error, though. The program runs normally. It just seems to skip the `File.open` method, and thus it doesn't create any file, and then it keeps going through the rest of the program. I made sure of it by creating a loop of file creation together with the line:

```
puts "whatever"
```

The loop is running correctly: I get "whatever" printed on screen thousands of times per second as expected, but still no file is created.

Now I need to tell you I've had this problem for weeks and never found a solution to it but it didn't bother me too much either since everything was working normally when I simply launched the program by double clicking on it instead of launching it through the command prompt.

However I now need to use it on Raspbian (on a Raspberry Pi Zero W), and I have the same issue when launching it through the terminal, but I know no other way to launch a Ruby program on Linux.

Here is the full code as required:

```
require 'io/console'

loop do
    hidden_data = '{"hidden_data":"true"}'
    File.open('hidden_data.json', "w") {|file| file.puts hidden_data }

    puts "Insert your password:"

    password = STDIN.noecho(&:gets).chomp

    if password == "1234"
        hidden_data = '{"hidden_data":"false"}'
        File.open('hidden_data.json', "w") {|file| file.puts hidden_data }
        puts "Access granted"
        sleep 60
    else
        puts "Wrong password"
    end
end
```

Comment: Code Please See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also what do you mean "launch"? You are calling `ruby /some/path/to/script.rb` correct?

Comment: You need to provide more details, such as the code, for us to help answer the question.

Comment: "Launch" might not be the correct word. How about "execute" ? 

Yes, I am pretty sure the path is correct. The program executes correctly, anyway. It's just that it skips all the "File.open" methods it sees on it's path.

Comment: @BlindLegsParker:  engineersmnky was not asking if your path is correct. He was asking if you invoke that ruby script with a full path like that. If that's the case, the files are created in the working dir (the directory you are currently at in the terminal), not in the `/some/path/to/`

Comment: You, sirs, are geniuses. Problem solved. Sometimes after hearing the solution to a problem that has plagued me for so long I feel stupid to not have thought about it alone. This time I still feel stupid because the solution was right under my nose, but I'm certain I couldn't have found it alone: I really wasn't looking in that direction. Thanks to all three of you.

Comment: @BlindLegsParker "You, sirs, are geniuses." - nah. We simply had seen too many rookie mistakes :)